# How to save an Bitmap ArrayList to a file

Tags: java, android, image, list, bitmap

I am trying to save a Bitmap List to a file. Basically, I want to store it for future reference so that when a user selects an image from gallery it stays there even when app closes.

This is what I am trying to do? But getting  a number of  Exception- BufferUnderFlowException, OutOfMemoryException. The problem seems to be very large memory of Bitmap List. Is there any better way to do this?

```
    final   List<Bitmap> bitmapcontent=new ArrayList<Bitmap>();
     ImageView imageView;
Gallery gallery;

private static byte[] bytesar;
ByteBuffer dst;
private void savethebitmap() throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException {

    try {
        FileOutputStream fos = openFileOutput("bitmapimage", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        ObjectOutputStream out=new ObjectOutputStream(fos);
        out.writeInt(bitmapcontent.size());

        for(int i=0;i<bitmapcontent.size();i++){

            out.writeInt(bitmapcontent.get(i).getRowBytes());
            out.writeInt(bitmapcontent.get(i).getHeight());
            out.writeInt(bitmapcontent.get(i).getWidth());


            int bmSize = bitmapcontent.get(i).getRowBytes() * bitmapcontent.get(i).getHeight();
            if(dst==null || bmSize > dst.capacity())
                dst= ByteBuffer.allocate(bmSize);

            out.writeInt(dst.capacity());
            dst.position(0);

            bitmapcontent.get(i).copyPixelsToBuffer(dst);
            if(bytesar==null || bmSize > bytesar.length)
                bytesar=new byte[bmSize];

            dst.position(0);
            dst.get(bytesar);


            out.write(bytesar, 0, bytesar.length);

        }


    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

private void loadthebitmap() throws IOException,ClassNotFoundException{

    try {
        freeBitmaps();
        FileInputStream fos = openFileInput("bitmapimage");
        ObjectInputStream in=new ObjectInputStream(fos);
        int size=in.readInt();
        for(int i=0;i<size;i++){

             int height=in.readInt();
                int width=in.readInt();

                int bmSize=in.readInt();




                if(bytesar==null || bmSize > bytesar.length)
                    bytesar= new byte[bmSize];


                int offset=0;

                while(in.available()>0){
                    offset=offset + in.read(bytesar, offset, in.available());
                }

                if(dst==null || bmSize > dst.capacity())
                    dst= ByteBuffer.allocate(bmSize);
                dst.position(0);
                dst.put(bytesar);
                dst.position(0);
            Bitmap    myVideoScreenshotBm=Bitmap.createBitmap(width, height, Bitmap.Config.RGB_565);
                myVideoScreenshotBm.copyPixelsFromBuffer(dst);
             bitmapcontent.add(myVideoScreenshotBm);



        }


    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: Post the printStackTrace also.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible that the arraylist is too big and the heap cannot handle it. Try launching the VM with:

```
-Xmx2G -Xms1G
```

-Xmx stands for max memory and -Xms stands for memory allocated at the start.
G stands for GB and M stands for MB.

Replying to G_S in the comment above, it seems that he has used `ObjectOutputStream` to serialize the arraylist.

Edit:

If the device dosen't have much memory you may want to try breaking up the bitmap into pieces, like chunks.

Comment: It is android device I don't know where so much memory will come from.

Answer (score 0):

`out.writeObject(bitmapContent)` and Bob (should be) your uncle... If you're running out of memory on that, use the suggestion to increase your memory size. And there are [further tips](http://javarevisited.blogspot.sg/2011/11/hotspot-jvm-options-java-examples.html) as well. All the best and let me know how you get on.

Answer (score 0):

`ObjectOutputStream` caches the object written to it. So either use simple `DataOutputStream` or call [`ObjectOutputStream.reset`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/ObjectOutputStream.html#reset%28%29)

```
    out.write(bytesar, 0, bytesar.length);
    out.flush();
    out.reset();
```

Comment: Well it helped but OutOfMemoryException still not gone.